# Impartial Combinatorial Games as a core of the final undergraduate project

Tags: application-of-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, project-topic

Solving several problems of Impartial Combinatorial Games in Game Theory has drawn my attention. So that, I'd like to ask if it's possible to use this topic (e.g. Sprague Grundy theorem) as a core or the main idea of my final year project in computer science.

P.S. I will do this project individually, and I may make any decision depending on your advice and suggestions.

Edit: Any additional information needed?

Comment: Isn't this a question to ask your professor?

Comment: @SashoNikolov Game Theory was mentioned partially in the Artificial Intelligent course in my university, and there is no other course teach it in any other programs, which motivated me to study it on my own from another university. However, it's up to me to work on any project I prefer.

Comment: Artificial Intelligence*